# Parsley in a jar - looks miserable and sick

Tags: houseplants, diagnosis, herbs, parsley

Yesterday (Apr 9) I bought a fresh tuft of parsley at the supermarket, packed in a paper cone with **its roots still wet**. Never seen before, they claim it would stay fresh if properly treated.

So, having not a pot with drain holes, my last resort is a **glass jar**. I put some **pebbles on the bottom, a layer of paper, and some soil**, where I planted the parsley. I gave it a **single spoon of water right on the center of the cluster** of stems at morning and evening, to make sure that no nasty pile up of water on the bottom would cause root rotting. Unfortunately, my studio flat is not that lighty, and gets **direct sunlight for some three hours a day**.

After a single day, even if I am definitely not an expert, and never grew parsley before, having compared with some pictures I found on google (I am sorry for my bizarre approach to gardening), I reckon my parsley is begging for mercy and for a quick but painless death. I attach a picture to both scare you and let you understand what is wrong with it.

Would you please tell me what you think it is going on and what it needs to be fixed? What would it be the best way to let the tuft thrive?[image: tuft of parsley in glass jar - SOS]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It needs to root into the soil and it needs more water - you really do need to find a pot with drainage holes and transfer it to that,  using fresh potting soil to plant it into,then give it a  good soak, let it drain down, and after that,keep it watered when the surface of the soil feels dry to the touch. Empty out any outer tray or pot 30 minutes after watering. If you do this, even if a lot of the existing growth dies off, it should, once settled, start to produce new growth IF it gets enough bright daylight.

Comment: Thank you @Bamboo, I found a half empty plastic bottle, drank the content, and pierced it several times on the bottom, checking if it actually drains. Apparently it works. I noticed that some sprouts already look stronger and stand up easier than just 1 hour ago. Is it me hallucinating or is it a reasonable reaction?

Comment: I can't answer that! Hope sometimes fools our eyes, but in theory, if you're now able to give it sufficient water as and when necessary because excess can drain, then yes,it should start to recover.

Comment: Hello, actually after three days the parsley looks *much better*, some stems are able to stand up quite fiercely, and I am so happy about it. Many thanks.